# How to detect client country

Tags: jsp, geolocation

I challenged a problem to detect the client browser location and locality. I search a google a lot of time but there is no correct answer, java.util.Locale is not working properly. Is there any solution please share with me

Answer (score 3):

The reason why `java.util.Locale` won't work, is that, **it uses your server's locale**, not the client's.

You can obtain information like the user's system language from its browser's user agent.

For more detailed information, like the user's location, there are different ways. One way is to use [HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_geolocation.asp):

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

**The thing is, that you can't rely on getting the geolocation.** My browser (Safari) always asks me to give the website my location. So I'm able to deny it. The user agent string is always there. It may get changed, but you should always be able to retrieve it. *Though there may be no prefered language in neither, so you need a fallback default.*

*Edit:* Obviously there is also a way to get the client's preferred `Locale` with `HttpServletRequest.getLocale()`. [According to the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale()), that will read the HTTP Accept-Language Header, which is another way to get the locale, but also isn't mandatory. If there isn't a locale, it will just return `null`.

*So until now you have atleast three ways to get your information. All depend on the browser and you sadly can't rely on one of these.*

Comment: I am using client locale, but the result will be different from one system to another system in same location, same ip address

Comment: Do these systems have the same browsers / OS? Also Geolocation depends on near WiFis and may not be very correct.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use User-Agent to obtain the information you need. Using JSP you can get it as follows:

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

which contains most of the client information in a String similar to the following:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.1 Safari/537.36
```

In addition to that, you can use ServletRequest's getLocale() method which will return the Locale based on Accept-Language header.

Comment: in windows system, the result is looks like  "userAgent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36". Here there is no locale.

Comment: Have you tried using getLocale() of HTTPServletRequest? I.e. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale()

Comment: As the docs say, getLocale() just parses the locale from the user agent. If there is no preferred locale, it won't give you extra information.

Comment: Misread... it will get it from an HTTP Header, which doesn't have to be set either...

Comment: Yes, it will get the Locale from Accept-Language header. It may not be set by the client as you said but still this is the standard way, not sure if there is any other way to obtain Locale if the user doesn't set it.

Answer (score 0):

With below you can find geographical info.

http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_geolocation.asp

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Location and locale are different questions.

Location (country, region etc) detection is based on IP address. You can google "geolocation by ip java" and see a lot of references. For example this one: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-find-location-using-ip-address/

Locale is detected from HTTP header. Google "locale from http request" and see the reference. For example: [Specifying locale for http request/response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465299/specifying-locale-for-http-request-response)

Shortly, HTTP headers `Accept-Language` and `Accept-Charset` are your friends.